# Trying to add both text and image to onmouseover

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I'm still a newbie and trying to add an image to a description of a project. Theoretically, when the user mouses over the project, an image and description will display in the column beside it. I know there's something I'm doing wrong with the double and single quotes, but I'm not sure what it is.

```
            function gettip(txt)
            {
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML=txt;
            }
function reset()
{
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML="Roll over a link for information on the project! "
}


<a href="Homework.html" 
               onmouseover="gettip('<img src='Images/homeworkpreview.jpg'><br><br><b>Due:</b> January 27 <br> <b>Points:</b> 50 <br> <br> <b> Description: </b> <br> Create a Homework page with a table with information about the projects for this semester. This will act as the hub for all of your projects to be linked to.')" 
               onmouseout="reset()"> Homework </a>
```

Comment: You'll need to escape them, like so `<img src=\'Images/homeworkpreview.jpg\'>`

Comment: An easier solution is just use backticks, which will auto-escape any quotes it contains. I've posted an example in my answer below

Comment: @BrendanC. template literals are not supported in Internet Explorer among others (https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals) -- not sure which browser the OP is running this code though. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I will add that info to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backticks (`) which will allow you to use single/double quotes within your `txt`. For example: `` gettip(`This 'string' can include "quotes"`) ``

For your case:

```
onmouseover="gettip(`<img src='Images/homeworkpreview.jpg'><br><br><b>Due:</b> January 27 <br> <b>Points:</b> 50 <br> <br> <b> Description: </b> <br> Create a Homework page with a table with information about the projects for this semester. This will act as the hub for all of your projects to be linked to.`)"
```

Note: [this will work for ~95% of users](https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals). If you need more coverage, you can escape quotes as other answers here indicate.

Answer (score 0):

After you've escape the single quotes, you'll need some element with the id `info`, something like:

```js
function gettip(txt) {
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = txt;
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =
    "Roll over a link for information on the project! ";
}
```

```html
<a href="Homework.html" onmouseover="gettip('<img src=\'Images/homeworkpreview.jpg\'><br><br><b>Due:</b> January 27 <br> <b>Points:</b> 50 <br> <br> <b> Description: </b> <br> Create a Homework page with a table with information about the projects for this semester. This will act as the hub for all of your projects to be linked to.')"
  onmouseout="reset()">
      Homework
    </a>
<div id="info"></div>
```